# Prometheus Alertmanager - how to list silences using REST?

Tags: rest, prometheus

What is the REST API request to list all the silences on a Prometheus's Alertmanager? this isn't documented anywhere except for the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've dug through the code - here's the request that's used to get all the silences, as of version 0.5.0:

```
curl localhost:9093/api/v1/silences -X GET
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57391859 might be useful for what I was looking for and needed