# PromQL: query whether an alert is silenced

Tags: alert, prometheus, promql

I have successfully silenced an alert for a node that's currently down (and will be for a while before we have time to replace it physically).

While I assume the silence will stop the alert from re-surfacing in the slack-channel I'd also like to get rid of it on the grafana dashboard we run over the top of prometheus. Here's the query for the respective tile in grafana.

```
sum(ALERTS{alertname="NodeDown", alertstate="firing"})
```

My questions is whether there's a keyword that I can replace "firing" with, "not silenced" doesn't work (neither does "silenced " ;}) that will only show me machines whose alerts aren't silenced.

Answer (score 3):

Silences exist entirely in the Alertmanager, Prometheus doesn't know anything about them. Thus there's no metric that'll let you know that the alert is silenced inside Prometheus.

Comment: Thanks (both for the response and the great product)  - understood.  Would it be feasible to harvest alert stats from the alertmanager (hoping that I can expose "silenced" somehow) and ingest those into prometheus as a metric?

Comment: Technically it should be possible, though it may not be the best idea overall.

Comment: what would be best practice to get rid of a triggered alert temporarily? I know the machine is gone for another 2 weeks ... removing it from monitoring seems silly, I'd have to remember adding it again when it gets fixed. :/

Comment: That's what silences are for :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a prometheus job to scrape alertmanager. then you get metrics like `alertmanager_silences`

```
# HELP alertmanager_silences How many silences by state.
alertmanager_silences{state="active"} 0
alertmanager_silences{state="expired"} 0
alertmanager_silences{state="pending"} 0
```

Comment: Hi @Rafa ... while this looks like an interesting metric to investigate your answer doesn't address my problem at all ...

Comment: @tink ooops. sorry. misunderstood then

Comment: add prometheus job to scrape alertmanager metrics and you will get these metrics 
`alertmanager_silences{}`

    - job_name: 'alertmanager'
        static_configs:
                - targets: prometheus1.foo.bar:9093']

Answer (score -1):

For my use case to get a metric about how many silenced alerts we have, while I was searching the web, Rafa's answer helped me to realize how to do it, that I have to scrape alertmanager target itself to get some metrics out of it.

I have added prometheus job to scrape alertmanager metrics and you  get these `GAUGE` metrics
`alertmanager_silences{}`

```
# HELP alertmanager_silences How many silences by state.
# TYPE alertmanager_silences gauge

alertmanager_silences{state="active"} 0
alertmanager_silences{state="expired"} 0
alertmanager_silences{state="pending"} 0
```

```
    - job_name: 'alertmanager'
      static_configs: 
        - targets: prometheus1.foo.bar:9093']
```

Comment: You're just [copying my answer from 4 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57391859/279564)... , which was already mentioned does not even answer the specific problem (because we cannot tell if a _specific_ alert is being silenced)

Comment: yeah, sorry for that, for my use case it was not for _specific_ alert but to get a metric how many silenced alerts we have, so while searching the web your answer helped me, I'll edit my post.